# VBA test format of text/value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a sub that exports a DXF file as text into my sheet and then take some values out of that.

I have two problems :
    --> The first being how to keep the format of a value I export in a sheet?
    --> And the second one being how to test the format of a value ?

I have different types of value in the file that I'm exporting :

- Text
- Integer "10", "20", "21" etc.. which tells me what kind of value comes after
- Actual values that I want (which kind was given by the integer), written as xxx.xxxx ("0.0000", "50.0000" or 120.0000 for example so always 4 zeros after the dot)
  In the file it looks like this :

  CONTINUOUS
  10
  50.0000
  20
  120.0000
  30
  0.0000
  40
  50.0000
  50
  0.0000
  51
  180.0000
  62
  5
  0

So my issue is that excel doesn't keep my values as they are when I export it. If it is 50.0000 it will write 50 and then I can't differentiate the types of the values... All the solution I found were about getting all my data as a format #.000 but that doesn't solve my problem...

Here is my sub :

```
Sub ImportDXF()
Dim fName As String
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ClearContents

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("DXF Files (*.dxf), *.dxf")
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Dim v As Variant
Dim r As Long
r = 2 'from row 2

Open fName For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, Line$
    Rows(r).Columns(1) = Trim(Line$)
    r = r + 1
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

And then I have another sub that will make something with the values I have exported so I want to test if this is an integer value or a float..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to test each value as you read it from the input DXF file. Then, apply an appropriate format to the cell with that value so it shows properly in your spreadsheet.

```
Sub ImportDXF()
    Dim fName As String
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ClearContents

    fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("DXF Files (*.dxf), *.dxf")
    If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    r = 2                                        'from row 2

    Open fName For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Input #1, Line$
        If IsNumeric(Line$) Then
            '--- we have a number, but what kind?
            If InStr(1, Line$, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                '--- we have a VALUE, so format to show the decimals
                Cells(r, 1).NumberFormat = "#0.0000"
            Else
                '--- we have a value ID, format with no decimals
                Cells(r, 1).NumberFormat = "#0"
            End If
        Else
            '--- we have text
            Cells(r, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
        End If
        Cells(r, 1).Value = Trim(Line$)
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ! I don't know why I didn't think about searching for the dot in the string before...